# How to Move Title Tab Indicator in Action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabactivity

After adding too many tabs in action bar, the tab title text are becomes small and close to each other. I tried to change width of action bar but it doesn't help. Kindly help me and sorry for my bad language. Here is my coding so far,

MainActivity.java

```
package com.topitideas.dailymasnoonduain;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Page 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Page 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Page 3"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Page 4"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Page 5"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Page 6"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Page 7"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Page 8"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Page 9"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Page 10"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Page 11"));


        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }


        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

PagerAdapter.java

```
package com.topitideas.dailymasnoonduain;

/**
 * Created by Saeed on 11/9/2015.
 */
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Home tab1 = new Home();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Page1 tab2 = new Page1();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Page2 tab3 = new Page2();
                return tab3;
            case 3:
                Page3 tab4 = new Page3();
                return tab4;
            case 4:
                Page4 tab5 = new Page4();
                return tab5;
            case 5:
                Page5 tab6 = new Page5();
                return tab6;
            case 6:
                Page6 tab7 = new Page6();
                return tab7;
            case 7:
                Page7 tab8 = new Page7();
                return tab8;
            case 8:
                Page8 tab9 = new Page8();
                return tab9;
            case 9:
                Page9 tab10 = new Page9();
                return tab10;
            case 10:
                Page10 tab11 = new Page10();
                return tab11;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your TabLayout scrollable. Just add `app:tabMode="scrollable"` in your layout xml.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

Comment: Thanks iamkaan it works and thumbs up for your precious reply here saves many times :)